Todolist: Remove dynamically added divs
I have a kind of todolist, in which I add elements when clicking on the 'add' button. There are two default lines. The add function works great, here's the original code


$(function() {
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output"
    }).insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last"));
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text" tabindex="1" /></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text 2" tabindex="2"></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div>customText{{[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output"></span><span class="output"></span></span>]}}</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>



Now, I've added a button to delete the lines. This is where it gets stuck.
For example: I add two rows to have 4 in total. For example, each line has one letter on it. (a,b,c,d) I delete "b,c,d" and I leave "a"; When I add more, the added text will be inserted before the "a" when it should come after. If I keep adding more, a text will replace an existing text, instead of being added.
Moreover I would like that in my span.output, there is never a pipe before the first text.
Does anyone have any idea where the problem comes from?
Here is my updated code:


$(function() {
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      id: "custom-text-" + count,
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output",
      dataid: "custom-text-" + count
    }).insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last"));
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
    var j = $(this).parent().find('.input').attr("id");
    $('#custom_wrapper .output[dataid="' + j + '"').empty();
  })

})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" id="custom-text-1" placeholder="custom text" tabindex="1" /></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" id="custom-text-2" placeholder="custom text 2" tabindex="2"></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="token">{{customText[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-1"></span><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-2"></span></span>]}}</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>




Is it possible that insertBefore() is the culprit?

But when I run this code, after adding 2 and removing all but the first, subsequent additions are inserted after the original input.

Do you want the number in the custom text to renumber or continue from the last added regardless of deletion?

Does this help?
Explanation: The reason for such behavior was because when an input row was being removed, the corresponding #custom_wrapper .output was not being removed. This was leading to desired elements not having the same indices, which was supposed to be same, and was being used on input event.
Extra changes: The id's of new elements were being assigned on the basis of children count, thus creating a case, where there might be multiple elements having same id. This code takes care of that as well.


$(function() {
  let nextInputId = 3;

  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    const i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    const v = $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    const count = $("input").length;

    const row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);

    $("<label>").appendTo(row);

    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      id: "custom-text-" + nextInputId,
      placeholder: "custom text " + (count + 1),
      tabindex: (count + 1)
    }).appendTo($("label", row));

    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);

    $("<span>", {
      class: "output",
      dataid: "custom-text-" + nextInputId
    }).appendTo($("#custom_wrapper"));

    nextInputId++;
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    const i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).remove();
    $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
  })
});
#custom_wrapper .output:not(:first-child):not(:empty)::before {
  content: "|"
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" id="custom-text-1" placeholder="custom text" tabindex="1" /></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" id="custom-text-2" placeholder="custom text 2" tabindex="2"></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div class="token">{{customText[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-1"></span><span class="output" dataid="custom-text-2"></span></span>]}}</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>




Please explain how you solved the problem here.

@mykaf I have updated the explanation in my answer :)

Thanks a lot Pranav..I think there is still a problem here.. Because When I add let's say: a,b,c,d, then delete d,c,b,a and I add text again, it is not carried over to the inputs. If I understand this code correctly const v = ((i == 0)? "" : "|") + $(this).val(); here there is a condition to say if there is no more text, we remove the pipe, but it is still there. Can we do i==1, to say if there is only one text we remove the pipe?

Ah, I zoomed in (I have a small vision problem) and in fact the pipe is well removed, sorry;)

@blogob does this solve your problem, or did I get something wrong?

yes sorry, in fact as I said, I tried your code here, and when deleting every row, we cannot add text anymore..You can try, if you add one or two rows, delete all the rows, then add text again,  it is not carried over to the inputs

@blogob yeah got that, there was a minor fix to be done for that in the code. I have updated the code accordingly.

thanks Pranav..can I ask you what did you change ? and also what does let nextInputId = 3 means ?  I also have question, tell me if I need to post another question for that ..From the code you produced, is there a possibility that the first text will never have a front pipe ?

@blogob Sure I will answer your queries. The last change I made was changing the way  span with class output was being added when new field was being added. Earlier, the code was .insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last")); which I replaced with .appendTo($("#custom_wrapper")); since when all the fields were removed, there was no .output:last element present, and thus no new span was being added to the DOM

The reason for using nextInputId = 3 ensures, that next id for newly created element does not already exists in DOM. It will always generate id not present in DOM already

@blogob You don't need to ask another question for that. Yes, the code ensures that only the text from second input field onwards have pipe character before them, and not the text from first input field.

thank you very much..I understand better. In the solution you provided, if I add "a, b", then delete a, the new "first" element has a pipe before it..do you know how to never display pipe for the first element ?

@blogob That case can be easily handled with CSS. I have updated the answer.

nice !! thanks a lot Pranav !!! you helped me a lot
